# Is there any notable difference between Excel and Excel-365 regarding the OLE interactivity?

Tags: excel, delphi, office365, ole

I am using the following Delphi OLE code to connect to the Excel application:

```
var
  ClassID: TCLSID;
  Unknown: IUnknown;
begin
  ClassID := ProgIDToClassID('Excel.Application');
  OleCheck(GetActiveObject(ClassID, nil, Unknown));
  OleCheck(Unknown.QueryInterface(IDispatch, Result));
end;
```

This code has worked for many Excel installations, but now it is run against Excel-365 and gives `Operation unavailable` message. I have not recreated yest the test environment to debug this code, but, generally - is there any difference between Excel and Excel-365 regarding how OLE interactivity happens from Delphi? Can I use the same Program ID, Class ID, Delphi wrapper objects to both Excel and Excel-365? Or maybe Excel 365 has different ProgID, ClassID?

Comment: Which line gives the `Operation unavailable`?

Comment: Excel in a browser window has no OLE automation so make sure they are in fact running the desktop versions and not the online version.

Comment: I have had issues in the past with Office not registering older interfaces that are still valid, but not what you're describing. An installed to disk Office 365 should have valid Excel.Application ProgID and you should be able to create it and query for IDispatch.

Comment: Problem solved - it appears, that Desktop Excel 365 has the same interfaces as Excel (as far as used by my application), but the problem was that my program was started with different user rights than the Excel program to whom it connected and that is why the exception was raised. When both - my program and Excel worksheet were started e.g. with administrator privileges that it worked on both types of Excel.